# Is there a way of making serde_json deserialize strictly?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

What I mean is that if 2 objects overlaps on some of the attributes is there a way to try to match **all** of them?
For example:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use serde_json; // 1.0.47; // 1.0.104

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct A {
    pub item_1: i32,
    pub item_2: i32,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct B {
    pub item_1: i32,
    pub item_2: i32,
    pub item_3: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let json_data = r#"{"item_1" : 10, "item_2" : 100, "item_3" : 1000}"#;
    if let Ok(data) = serde_json::from_str::<A>(json_data) {
        println!("{:?}", data);
    } else if let Ok(data) = serde_json::from_str::<B>(json_data) {
        println!("{:?}", data);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd214ffe0c613ecf5ffc7980bd053161)

It always succed on `A`, but I want it to fail because it has extra data so that it falls to `B` (where it matches exaclty). This is just an example of the problem I am having.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serde has many [attributes](https://serde.rs/attributes.html) to configure this kind of behavior.

One of them is [`#[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#deny_unknown_fields) which does exactly that:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json; // 1.0.47; // 1.0.104

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]
pub struct A {
    pub item_1: i32,
    pub item_2: i32,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct B {
    pub item_1: i32,
    pub item_2: i32,
    pub item_3: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let json_data = r#"{"item_1" : 10, "item_2" : 100, "item_3" : 1000}"#;
    if let Ok(data) = serde_json::from_str::<A>(json_data) {
        println!("{:?}", data);
    } else if let Ok(data) = serde_json::from_str::<B>(json_data) {
        println!("{:?}", data);
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
B { item_1: 10, item_2: 100, item_3: 1000 }
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=75525d1da1ec9b017afcbab3171ee596))